# Why is `db.query(Order).get(order_id)` behaving as O(n) and not O(log(n))? - SQLAlchemy and Python

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, orm

We have this service, with the method `get_order`, which for some reason increases linearly with the quantity of orders:

```py
from nameko.events import EventDispatcher
from nameko.rpc import rpc
from nameko_sqlalchemy import DatabaseSession

from orders.exceptions import NotFound
from orders.models import DeclarativeBase, Order, OrderDetail  # , Orders
from orders.schemas import OrderSchema


class OrdersService:
    name = "orders"

    db = DatabaseSession(DeclarativeBase)
    event_dispatcher = EventDispatcher()

    @rpc
    def get_order(self, order_id):
        order = self.db.query(Order).get(order_id)

        if not order:
            raise NotFound("Order with id {} not found".format(order_id))

        return OrderSchema().dump(order).data
```

The `Order`:

```py
class Order(DeclarativeBase):
    __tablename__ = "orders"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)


class OrderDetail(DeclarativeBase):
    __tablename__ = "order_details"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    order_id = Column(
        Integer, ForeignKey("orders.id", name="fk_order_details_orders"), nullable=False
    )
    order = relationship(Order, backref="order_details")
    product_id = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    price = Column(DECIMAL(18, 2), nullable=False)
    quantity = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
```

The OrderSchema:

```py
class OrderDetailSchema(Schema):
    id = fields.Int(required=True)
    product_id = fields.Str(required=True)
    price = fields.Decimal(as_string=True)
    quantity = fields.Int()


class OrderSchema(Schema):
    id = fields.Int(required=True)
    order_details = fields.Nested(OrderDetailSchema, many=True)
```

I expected a O(log(n)), or almost constant retrieval time. Instead, the result is a O(n) response.

[image: Graph hits vs. Execution time]

I hypothesize it's because `Order` becomes a list/vector. And, I should create something like `Orders` table and a `OrdersSchema`, as an object/dictionary and operate on key-values basis. But, I'm not so sure how to do it.

I tried and to use it, but without success.

```py
class OrdersSchema(Schema):
    id = fields.Int(required=True, autoincrement=True)
    order = fields.Nested(OrderSchema, many=False)
```

Comment: Is there an index on order_id in the data base?

Comment: @FrankYellin The `get()` method looks up a row by primary key. Primary keys are always indexed.

Comment: The `Query.get()` method is deprecated as part of the legacy query API. You shouldn't be using it in new code. You should use `Session.get()`

Comment: @FrankYellin https://github.com/BuddhiLW/ilia-technical-challenge I don't really know. Most of the code was from `nameko-devex` repository, as a initial example. Could you take a look? I think they are all indexed.

Comment: @Barmar just changing the code to `with self.db_orders.get_session() as session:` and using that `session` indeed greatly reduced the response-time. I will go with that answer. Thanks.